# formik form and yup, error not getting updated after action

Tags: reactjs, redux, formik, yup

```
<InputAutoSuggest
    name="name"
    suggestions={this.props.theatreSuggestions}
    onSuggestionsFetchRequested={this.props.onSuggestionsFetchRequested}
    onSuggestionsClearRequested={this.props.onSuggestionsClearRequested}
    getSuggestionValue={this.getSuggestionValue}
    renderSuggestion={this.renderSuggestion}
    inputPropsValue={this.props.newVal}
    value={this.props.value}
    onChange={setFieldValue}
    onBlur={setFieldTouched}
    error={errors.name}
    touched={touched.name} 
    onSuggestionSelected={this.onSuggestionSelected}
    newChange={this.props.newChange}
/>
{ errors.name && touched.name && <div className="invalid-feedbac">{errors.name}</div>}
```

So from here, it goes to autosuggest input action, but whenever I type something error continues to be shown.The form will not be submitted too

*Edit (from comments)*

Error description:

```
validationSchema={ Yup.object().shape({ name: Yup.string() .required("Theatre name is required!"), street1: Yup.string() .required("Street1 name is required!"),
```

so this is my schema and whenever I type in the name, it shows the validation message, theater name is required.

Comment: What error? You say it is shown, but could you show it to us? Please be aware that *we can't see your screen*, so try to give as many details as you can so we are able to understand what's wrong :)

Comment: validationSchema={
                Yup.object().shape({
                    name: Yup.string()
                      .required("Theatre name is required!"),
                    street1: Yup.string()
                        .required("Street1 name is required!"),           so this is my schema and whenever I type in the name, it shows the validation message, theater name is required.

Comment: Please, do not add important information in comment. Edit your post to include it instead.

Comment: Without the code of the component rendering the `<InputAutoSuggest>` it will be hard to tell. My guess is that you do not update your `errors` when the error should be removed, e.g. because the user typed something.

Comment: Guys, How do you solved this problem? Actually I have the same issue in my project